# Is there any way to remove the 'link to' text on new shortcuts?

Tags: directory, shortcuts

I find it very annoying that I have to take out the 'Link to' in the names of new shortcuts all the time in Ubuntu. Is there anyway of removing that text permenantly so it just isn't there when I make a new shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to prevent "Link to" to be appended to a link (shortcut) created with the right-click menu option "Create Link" (an option that needs to be enabled in "Preferences"). Yet, it probably would be a bad thing if there was. The "Create Link" option creates a symbolic link in the same folder. That symbolic link therefore cannot have the same name as the target.

When you create a symbolic link in a different folder, Files will *not* prepend the "Link to" prefix. In only does when you create a symbolic link in the same folder.